# ¿Cuál es correcto "tomar prestado libros" o "tomar prestados libros"?

Tags: plurales, concordancia-gramatical

Consideren las siguientes dos frases:

- *Ayer tomé prestado algunos libros de la biblioteca.*
- *Ayer tomé prestados algunos libros de la biblioteca.*

La primera frase suena raro para mí. Yo prefiero la segunda frase, me suena más natural. Sin embargo he notado que a algunas personas les gusta más la primera frase.

Algo de contexto:

Alguien me hizo una pregunta en persona, algo como "¿me podrías dar prestado tus auriculares?", pensé que la frase estaba mal, debería ser "¿me podrías dar prestados tus auriculares?".

Así que pregunté en una app llamada "yask" (donde nativos le dan votitos a la frase que les parezca mas natural, y también corrigen las frases). Lo curioso es que la mitad de los que contestaron pensaban que "prestado" era correcto :S.

Buscando en internet encuentro un par de ejemplos:

- "tomar prestado libros" amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=200901280

**Nota:**

Pregunté en la aplicación (yask) cuál de las siguientes dos frases les parecía correcta:

- *Ayer tomé algunos libros prestado de la biblioteca*
- *Ayer tomé algunos libros prestados de la biblioteca*

Y en este caso, todos, sin excepción, votaron por la segunda frase. A ninguno de ellos les parecía mejor la primera que la segunda.

La mayoría de los usuarios de la aplicación en español son latinos, así que la diferencia posiblemente solo se ve en Hispanoamérica.

He aquí las capturas de pantalla de las votaciones que he tomado de yask:

[image] [image] [image]

Comment: Prestados es un adjetivo que se refiere a "libros", en plural, luego el adjetivo debe ir en plural (prestados).

Comment: ¡Bienvenido/a al sitio! Interesante pregunta. ¿Y si reordenamos un poco la frase? ¿Cómo te suena "ayer tomé algunos libros prestado de la biblioteca"?

Comment: @walen Alguien me hizo una pregunta en persona, algo como "¿me podrías dar prestado tus auriculares?", pensé que estaba mal. Así que pregunté en una app llamada "yask" (donde nativos le dan votitos a la frase que les parezca mas natural, y también corrigen las frases). Lo curioso es que la mitad de los que contestaron pensaban que "prestado" era correcto :S. Buscando en internet encuentro un par de ejemplos, uno de ellos "tomar prestado libros" https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=200901280

Comment: @Charlie Me suena aún más raro, voy a preguntar de nuevo a ver si les parece raro también a los otros

Comment: @FGSUZ eso tiene sentido. Muchas gracias por la aclaración. Sin embargo me pregunto si alguien a documentado este "error" (que parece ser bastante común en algunos lugares)

Comment: Volví a hacer la pregunta en la aplicación (yask) tal como @Charlie la planteó. Todos respondieron que la frase que mejor suena es "ayer tomé algunos libros prestados de la biblioteca"

Comment: no se... pero los participios no pluralizados al estar en compañía de  sustantivos plurales me suenan horribles, nótese como lo he utilizado en mi comentario.

Comment: @walen listo, sólo una persona (de 14) comentó esta vez que prefiere el singular en la frase que usa "enciclopedia"

Comment: Estas en lo correcto @walen, de tanto estar leyendo "prestado" y "prestados" ya mi cerebro no estaba diferenciando. No me fijé que la respuesta de Charlie no tenía nada con "tomar prestado" (singular). A decir verdad, la respuesta que más se acerca es la de un tal walen ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Voy a poner una respuesta, a pesar de que no tengo (aún) las fuentes necesarias para respaldarla, porque es una pregunta que me parece interesante y me choca que nadie haya respondido aún*.

En mi opinión, en este caso, lo que encontramos son dos construcciones distintas:

- "**Tomar** *algo* prestado", donde "**tomar**" es el **verbo**, "*algo*" es el objeto directo, y "prestado" un adjetivo en concordancia con "algo";
- "**Tomar prestado** *algo*", donde "**tomar prestado**" funciona como **locución verbal**, y "*algo*" como su objeto directo.

Si entendemos "tomar prestado" como locución verbal, es decir como un grupo único, entonces se comprende que "prestado" ya no tenga por qué ir en concordancia con el objeto directo, pues no funciona como adjetivo de este sino como parte fija de la locución.
En el momento en que rompemos la locución, convirtiendo la segunda frase en la primera, entonces ningún hablante tiene dudas de que "prestado" funciona (ahora sí) como adjetivo y por tanto debe concordar.

No se me ocurren muchos ejemplos de otros casos similares, pero uno posible podría ser "hacerse el muerto". Compárese:

> Mis amigos se hicieron los muertos.
>   Mis amigos se hicieron el muerto.

Está claro que no todos los amigos se hicieron el mismo muerto, sin embargo se puede tomar "hacerse el muerto" como una locución verbal y en tal caso se comprendería el segundo uso.

Una manera de comprobar si efectivamente se está usando "tomar prestado" como locución, sería pedir que la usen con un objeto de género femenino. Los resultados serán:

- *"Ayer tomé prestada una enciclopedia de la biblioteca"* → uso como verbo + adjetivo
- *"Ayer tomé prestado una enciclopedia de la biblioteca"* → uso como locución verbal

<sub>* Antes hablo, antes responde alguien... jajaja</sub>

Comment: Experimentando un poco más, la frase "mis amigos se hicieron el muerto" no es querida por nadie. He aquí los resultados: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgLGd.png

Comment: @helq Es curioso, yo creo que habría usado *se hicieron el muerto* en este caso.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que la confusión puede venir del hecho de que *prestado* puede funcionar tanto como participio como adjetivo en ese tipo de construcciones.

Ejemplo como participio:

> Mi amigo me ha prestado cuatro libros.

Nótese que en estos casos el participio se mantiene invariable ante género y número:

> Mi amigo me ha prestado tres alfombras.

Sin embargo, en las construcciones donde funciona como adjetivo sí debe variar en cuanto a género y número:

> He tomado prestados cuatro libros = He tomado cuatro libros prestados.
>   Tengo prestadas tres alfombras = Tengo tres alfombras prestadas.

Tienes más información al respecto en las secciones [27.10](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=wepKEyRDchkbiQpE) y [27.11](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=OuOhUUElfYIkObdQ) de la Gramática de la RAE.

Comment: por que no estas usando el participio en los primeros ejemplos, ahi utilizas el presente perfecto, no un gerundio, recuerda que el participio en esta frase funciona como un adjetivo, no como verbo

Comment: @mike en español se le llama al tiempo de *ha prestado* el *pretérito perfecto compuesto* o *antepresente*.  En la gramática española, el participio (correspondiente al participio pasado en la gramática inglesa) se usa en esa construcción y termina en *-ado* o *-ido*.  El gerundio (correspondiente al participio presente no adjetivado en la gramática inglesa) es la forma que termina en *-ando* o *-iendo*. En la gramática española hay otro tipo de participio, ya poco usado excepto en formas lexicalizadas hace mucho, que se llama el participio activo y termina en *-ante* o *-(i)ente*.

Comment: Más que el hecho de que sea participio, creo que la confusión puede venir de que "tomar prestado", se pudiera interpretar, en conjunto, como una locución verbal.

Answer (score 1):

El español admite tanto "tomar prestados algunos libros" como "tomar algunos libros prestados". Depende de donde el locutor pone el énfasis: en el acto de tomar prestado o en los libros. Algunos libros, no son discos.

He encontrado un excelentísimo trabajo sobre esta cuestión, de la cual sobresalen dos puntos importantes que vienen a colación aqui.

> El adjetivo que precede al sustantivo se encuentra más íntimamente
> unido a él, mientras que el que sigue, si bien aparece más acentuado,
> se halla más separado. El primero modifica el concepto del sustantivo
> antes de que éste se haya emitido; el segundo, por su parte,
> constituye una especie de rectificación y restricción del término
> sustantivo general y vago ya enunciado. Por ello, «las cualidades
> primitivas, generales e interiores, se anteponen; las derivadas,
> complejas y exteriores, se posponen» (ibid.)
>
> a) El español, como las restantes lenguas románicas, muestra una clara
> tendencia a la posposición del adjetivo al sustantivo en el grupo
> sintagmático nominal, a pesar de lo cual **no impide que el hablante
> disponga de un amplio margen de libertad a la hora de decidir el orden
> en que hayan de aparecer las categorías modificadora y modificada**.
>
> b) La posición del adjetivo en nuestro idioma, aunque libre, no es
> caprichosa. En general, su variación, en la que influyen
> circunstancias de diversa índole (histórica, semántica, estética,
> fónica, contextual...), permite expresar matices de gran precisión y
> riqueza.

[Gramática y estilística de la posición del ajetivo en español](https://revistas.ucm.es/index.php/DIDA/article/viewFile/DIDA9595110073A/20026)

Se admite "tomar prestados algunos libros" y "tomar algunos libros prestados".